# Deterministic sinusoidal function for primality?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

According to Wilsons`s Theorem in a modification by Leibniz, we have that

**(p – 2)! ≡ 1 (mod p)** for all **p > 2**.

Then, we should also have that the term (quotient *q*)

[image]

is a positive integer, while, if one substitutes *n* for *p*, the values of *q* should not be integers but fractions.

Then, the function

[image]

should have its zeroes at *n* being prime numbers (only).

As simple as that...: Am I right?

Comment: Wilson's theorem is not a useful primality test. Computing factorials, even $\bmod p$, is quite a bit more time-consuming than trial division. Try testing whether $2021$ is prime this way and see how far you get!

Comment: You can even omit the square in $f(n)$. The catch is that the argument is far too large to compute the sine, if $n$ has , lets say , $20$ digits.